# possible to have two different foreign keys in AR relationship model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a problematic relationship where there are items that can be bundled into a car.

for example:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :object_connections, :foreign_key => 'engine_id'
  has_many :object_connections, :foreign_key => 'chassis_id'
```

It looks like it only looks at the last. Is there any way to specify either? Also, is it possible to add conditions like `:is_engine => true`? This is an adopted project and just trying to get this to work.

thx

Comment: You can only use an association name (i.e. the first argument after `has_many`) once in a model. Can you tell us more about your models? What associations does ObjectConnection have? Are there Engine and Chassis models as well?

Comment: Basically, there are items and there are object_connection's which are made up of 'item'. An item is internally managed as either an engine or a chasis. This part is the wankiest part of the schema. I suspect that I'll just have to do this custom since we only really do it on a query. Looks like the conditions query the other table which is not so much help.

Comment: How is it internally managed? Can you show us the associations code and the relevant database fields from the other three models?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a [`has_one` association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_one-association-reference) with a `:class_name` option:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :engine,  :foreign_key => 'engine_id',  :class_name => 'ObjectConnection'
  has_one :chassis, :foreign_key => 'chassis_id', :class_name => 'ObjectConnection'
end
```

The associations need to be uniquely named and usually ActiveRecord can figure out the `:class_name` based on the association; you, however, have two things pointing at the same place so you have to wire it all up by hand.